# How to hide BottomNavigation bar in Nativescript

Tags: android, nativescript

Please how can i hide Bottom Navigation in a particular page in nativescript core?
The code for my BottomNavigation is in App-root.xml file. this makes it visible on all pages, i'm trying to hide it from a specific page. Below is my app-root.xml file

```
<BottomNavigation id="bottomNav">
    <TabStrip backgroundColor="#3f3f3f">
        <TabStripItem class="navigation__item">
            <!--
                Note TabStripItem will only accept single Label and/or single Image elements that it
                will "adopt"; any other layout elements you try to specify will be ignored
            -->
            <Label text="Play" />
            <Image src="font://&#xF04B;" class="fas t-36" />
        </TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem class="navigation__item">
            <Label text="Trending" />
            <Image src="font://&#xF75A;" class="fas t-36" />
        </TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem class="navigation__item">
            <Label text="Account" />
            <Image src="font://&#xF2BD;" class="fas t-36" />
        </TabStripItem>
    </TabStrip>

    <TabContentItem>
        <Frame defaultPage="home/home-items-page" />
    </TabContentItem>

    <TabContentItem>
        <Frame defaultPage="browse/browse-page" />
    </TabContentItem>

    <TabContentItem>
        <Frame defaultPage="search/search-page" />
    </TabContentItem>
</BottomNavigation>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is searching for a simple solution :
Try this:

```html
<TabStrip visibility="collapsed">
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You may toggle visibility of TabBar natively

To hide,

```
if (bottomNav.android) {
    bottomNav._bottomNavigationBar.setVisibility(android.view.View.GONE);
} else {
    bottomNav.viewController.tabBar.hidden = true;
}
```

To show it back,

```
if (bottomNav.android) {
    bottomNav._bottomNavigationBar.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    bottomNav.viewController.tabBar.hidden = false;
}
```

Where `bottomNav` should be instance of your `BottomNavigation` component.

Comment: thanks, but it says bottomNav is undefined, what can i do about this

Comment: As I mentioned `bottomNav` presumed to be the reference to your bottom navigation control. Assign a id, get it by id from controller and use it. If you are still having issues, please share the JS part of your code, how & when you are accessing the control.

Comment: `let bottomBar = page.getViewById("bottomNav");
    if (bottomBar.android) {
        bottomBar._bottomNavigationBar.setVisibility(android.view.View.GONE);
    } else {
        bottomBar.viewController.tabBar.hidden = true;
    }`  The bottomNav is in my App-root.xml

Comment: Please share a Playground sample where I could see the issue. It works on my end, tested with Android Pixels.

Comment: thanks, i was able to fix it with  `let bottomBar = application.getRootView();

    if (bottomBar.android) {
        bottomBar._bottomNavigationBar.setVisibility(android.view.View.GONE);
    } else {
        bottomBar.viewController.tabBar.hidden = true;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

```
let bottomBar = application.getRootView();

    if (bottomBar.android) {
        bottomBar._bottomNavigationBar.setVisibility(android.view.View.GONE);
    } else {
        bottomBar.viewController.tabBar.hidden = true;
    }
```